# can android webview remember a user?

Tags: android, webview

Like other browsers, when a user sign in to a web application he can remained signed in. For example, if a user sign in to facebook using google chrome, he remains signed in at google chrome.
Is there any way that, user will sign in from webview and that webview will remember the user through out the application running time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can get AccessToken and You can use to the AccessTokenTracker 
if user log out or chage profile in web , You can received callback.

```
 accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
            AccessToken oldAccessToken,
            AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // Set the access token using 
                // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
        }
    };
    // If the access token is available already assign it.
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}
```

[Facebook acesstokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/accesstokens)